# Open files in a vector, C++

Tags: c++, vector, ifstream

I have `totalSortedRuns` number of files. I want to open these in a vector. I used two methods for this:

```
vector<ifstream> files;
const char * fileName;
for(int i = 1; i<=totalSortedRuns; i++){
    fileName = (inputFileName + to_string(i)).c_str();
    files[i].open(fileName);
}
```

Tried this method because the method below wasn't working. This gives segmentation fault when I run it, obviously because my vector `files` is empty and I am assigning the value to its `0-th` element. To resolve this, I tried to assign `files.push_back(NULL)` but it gave me the error

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘std::vector<std::basic_ifstream<char> >::push_back(NULL)’
```

Method 2:

```
vector<ifstream> files;
ifstream file;
const char * fileName;
for(int i = 1; i<=totalSortedRuns; i++){
    fileName = (inputFileName + to_string(i)).c_str();
    file.open(fileName);
    files.push_back(file);   // line no 178 in code
}
```

But this gives me the error:

[image]

```
In file included from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/8/bits/c++allocator.h:33,
             from /usr/include/c++/8/bits/allocator.h:46,
             from /usr/include/c++/8/string:41,
             from /usr/include/c++/8/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
             from /usr/include/c++/8/bits/ios_base.h:41,
             from /usr/include/c++/8/ios:42,
             from /usr/include/c++/8/ostream:38,
             from /usr/include/c++/8/iostream:39,
             from invertedIndex.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/8/ext/new_allocator.h: In instantiation of ‘void __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<_Tp>::construct(_Up*, _Args&& ...) [with _Up = std::basic_ifstream<char>; _Args = {const std::basic_ifstream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&}; _Tp = std::basic_ifstream<char>]’:
/usr/include/c++/8/bits/alloc_traits.h:475:4:   required from ‘static void std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<_CharT> >::construct(std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<_CharT> >::allocator_type&, _Up*, _Args&& ...) [with _Up = std::basic_ifstream<char>; _Args = {const std::basic_ifstream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&}; _Tp = std::basic_ifstream<char>; std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<_CharT> >::allocator_type = std::allocator<std::basic_ifstream<char> >]’
/usr/include/c++/8/bits/stl_vector.h:1079:30:   required from ‘void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::push_back(const value_type&) [with _Tp = std::basic_ifstream<char>; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::basic_ifstream<char> >; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::value_type = std::basic_ifstream<char>]’
invertedIndex.cpp:178:29:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/8/ext/new_allocator.h:136:4: error: use of deleted function ‘std::basic_ifstream<_CharT, _Traits>::basic_ifstream(const std::basic_ifstream<_CharT, _Traits>&) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]’
{ ::new((void *)__p) _Up(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...); }
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/8/bits/stdc++.h:70,
             from invertedIndex.cpp:6:
/usr/include/c++/8/fstream:552:7: note: declared here
   basic_ifstream(const basic_ifstream&) = delete;
   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

From the line `invertedIndex.cpp:178:29:   required from here`, I understood that the error is in `files.push_back(file)`. I wasn't able to understand what exactly is this error and why.

Can someone please tell me how to do this(read files in vector)? Thanks...

Comment: You can initialize vector with a count, each of which will be default initialized. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector although I would just have a vector of the filenames, or a vector of the file contents. Holding a bunch of open handles like this is problematic on some OS for one thing.

Comment: Please post error messages as text into your question. I can't read linked images. A [mcve] helps to find the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is self-explanatory. The `ifstream` has a deleted copy constructor. By pushing the `ifstream` to the vector you've requested a copy. This can be solved by moving the file into the vector: `files.push_back(std::move(file))`.